# ORA-60019 : Creating initial extent of size 14 in tablespace of extent size 8

Tags: clob, tablespace

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Seeking help from experts to resolve the following error:

CREATE TABLE "BUILD_FILT"

( "BUILD_ID" NUMBER(38,0),

"BUILD_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),

"BUILD_IMPL" CLOB

)

ORA-60019 : Creating initial extent of size 14 in tablespace of extent size 8

*Cause:    Creation of SECUREFILE segment failed due to small tablespace

```
       extent size.
```

*Action:   Create tablespace with larger extent size and reissue command.

Answer (score 4):

The minimum extent size of the tablespace must be 1M when `db_securefile` is set to ALWAYS. If the extent size is less than 1M, the error ORA-60019 is reported.

For Oracle 12C, run the following command:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET db_securefile=NEVER scope=both;
```